# ¿Cómo puedo sumar floats de un array en Bash?

Tags: array, bash, float

Tengo un problema a la hora de sumar elementos de un array que he extraído de los datos de un fichero.

Este es mi script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t lines < <(grep '%Cpu*' 'top-output.txt' | tr -s ' ' -| cut 
-d "-" -f 2)      # Aquí obtengo los datos en el array lines
echo ${lines[@]}  # Aquí imprimo los datos y obtengo el resultado 

sum=$(IFS="+"; bc <<< "${lines[*]}" ) # El Syntax Error me da al hacer esto
echo $sum
```

Foto adjunta del `echo` del array:

[image: Datos del array]

Comment: Bienvenido Victor al sitio, buena pregunta y qué bien que lo resolvieras tú mismo. Nótese que es recomendable no subir imágenes, sino texto. De este modo es más fácil ayudarte pues podemos copiar el contenido y hacer pruebas nosotros.

Answer (score 3):

finalmente he dado con la solución.
Los floats obviamente van con '.' y mis resultados tenían comas de por medio y ahí fallaba la operación.

A la línea de código original sólo había que añadirle lo siguiente:

```
mapfile -t lines < <(grep '%Cpu*' 'top-output.txt' | tr -s ' ' -| cut -
d "-" -f 2 |tr -s ',' .)
```

Para cambiar comas por puntos

Answer (score 1):

También tienes la opción de buscar todos los números con `grep`, imprimir uno cada vez y finalmente sumarlos:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?' fichero | tr ',' '.' | awk '{suma += $1} END {print suma+0}'
```

Por partes:

- `grep -Eo '[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?' fichero`
  Busca todos los números, que están formados por una serie de números y seguidos, o no, por una coma y números decimales. Al usar `-o`, conseguimos que cada número aparezca en una línea.
- `tr ',' '.'`
  Sustituye las comas por puntos, para que se pueda sumar.
- `awk '{suma += $1} END {print suma+0}'`
  Suma cada número e imprime el resultado final. El `+0` nos sirve para inicializar la variable `suma` a 0 si es que no había ninguna línea.

Ejemplo paso a paso:

```
$ cat fichero
25,3 24,9
24,5
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?' fichero
25,3
24,9
24,5
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?' fichero | tr ',' '.' 
25.3
24.9
24.5
$ \grep -Eo '[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?' fichero | tr ',' '.' | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum+0}'
74.7
```